# PowerShell Get Groups from array

Tags: powershell

I have an array that looks like this:

```
EMPID         JOBTITLE
123           Customer Service Rep
456           Customer Service Rep
789           Customer Service Rep
213           General Clerk
234           General Clerk
```

I need to produce two files.

- File 1:

  ```
  Customer Service Rep
  123
  456
  789
  ```
- File 2:

  ```
  General Clerk
  213
  234
  ```

I realize this is scripting 101, but I'm a network guy without a lot of experience in scripting.  I've tried variations of `foreach` and `ForEach-Object`, but can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: Try using `Group` such as `$array | Group JOBTITLE | ForEach{ Set-Content "C:\Path\To\$($_.Name).txt" -Value $_.Group.JOBTITLE}`

Comment: Your array looks more like a table. Where does it come from? Is it an array of lines? Output of some external command? Also, please show your code, even if it doesn't work, so we can help you with the wrapping (i.e. explain what doesn't work and why, and how to fix it).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$data=@"
EMPID;JOBTITLE
123;Customer Service Rep
456;Customer Service Rep
789;Customer Service Rep
213;General Clerk
234;General Clerk
"@

$yourarray=$data | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

#if you considere your data into $yourarray
$Rank=0;
$yourarray | group JOBTITLE | %{$Rank++; $_.Name, $_.Group.EMPID | out-file "c:\temp\File_$Rank.txt"}
```